# Categorical focal loss on keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to use categorical focal loss in tf/keras. Binary Focal loss works for me but not the code I found for categorical f.l. Does someone have this ?

Comment: Right now focal loss is available in the offcial tensorflow-addons:
https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/sigmoid_focal_crossentropy
It is compatible with Keras API

Answer (score 9):

1. focal-loss 0.0.6
   https://pypi.org/project/focal-loss/
   includes the functions

- binary_focal_loss
- sparse_categorical_focal_loss

  ```
  pip install focal-loss
  ```

---

2. https://github.com/umbertogriffo/focal-loss-keras

- Binary

  ```
  model.compile(loss=[binary_focal_loss(alpha=.25, gamma=2)], metrics=["accuracy"], optimizer=adam)
  ```
- Categorical

  ```
  model.compile(loss=[categorical_focal_loss(alpha=[[.25, .25, .25]], gamma=2)], metrics=["accuracy"], optimizer=adam)
  ```

Answer (score 6):

Sure. I found [this](https://github.com/mkocabas/focal-loss-keras/blob/master/focal_loss.py) by googling `Keras focal loss`. It was the first result, and took even less time to implement.

[This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aldi-dimara/keras-focal-loss/master/focal_loss.py) was the second result on google. Tried it too, and it also works fine; took one of my classification problems up to roc score of 0.9726.

Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Categorical Focal Loss is now available (>TF 2.13) under `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalFocalCrossentropy()`. You can check the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalFocalCrossentropy) for the details.